# Applying Stirling's formula in testing for convergence of a sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I trying to figure which $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ make the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\beta n)^n}{n!}$ converge. I have tried two tests: ratio test, and approximation by Stirling's formula. I must be making a mistake with at least one of them, because they're giving me different answers.

If I try the ratio test, I get $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{(\beta n)^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{(\beta n)^n/n!}= \frac{\beta n}{n+1}\to \beta,$$which suggests that it converges at least for $\beta \in (-1,1)$.

But Stirling's formula is giving me that the general term is $$\frac{(\beta n)^n}{n!} \sim \frac{(\beta n)^n}{(n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}= \frac{\beta^n e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}},$$ which suggests that the general term does not even go to zero unless $\beta e<1$! This contradicts what I got previously. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Error or typo. You want $(\beta(n+1))^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last expression in the ratio test is wrong. Try again. $$\dfrac{{\dfrac{{{\beta ^{n + 1}}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{n + 1}}}}{{(n + 1)!}}}}{{\dfrac{{{\beta ^n}{n^n}}}{{n!}}}} = \dfrac{1}{{n + 1}}\dfrac{{{\beta ^{n + 1}}}}{{{\beta ^n}}}\frac{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{n + 1}}}}{{{n^n}}} = \beta {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n} \to \beta e$$

Comment: Duh! Thanks Peter